# psql run sql file result

Tags: sql, postgresql, cmd, psql

When I run my command:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U meee -d my_db -f sqltest.sql
```

it displays:

```
CREATE VIEW
ALTER TABLE
```

However I want it to show me just like pgadmin show it (for exmpl: The query was executed successfully in 45 ms, but returns no results)

Comment: `\timing on`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: oh thanks. but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

add at the beginning of ´sqltest.sql´ the command ´\timing´ and you will see the time of each command

for example script.sql :
`\timing select 2 ; select 1; create table tablax(i int);`

Or if you want all time from the begining of the  script until end, add some command to script
at the beginning:
`create temp table tab (time1 time,time2 time); insert into tab (time1) select now()::time;`

at the end:
`update tab set time2=now()::time; select time2-time1 as time_Elapsed from tab;`

for example:

```
create temp table tab (time1 time,time2 time);
```

`insert into tab (time1) select now()::time;`

...
your script code

...`update tab set time2=now()::time; select time2-time1 as time_Elapsed from tab;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `a` psql command parameter:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U meee -d my_db -af sqltest.sql
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

And place `\timing on` at the top of your script